# SQL query using foreign key from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a project using java,jsp, and sql. I have 2 tables one called shop and one called event. Event has an attribute called shopcode which is the primary key of the table shop. I want a query which is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM event where event.shopcode=?
```

I've tried this sql query with INNER JOIN:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM event INNER JOIN shop ON event.shopcode=shop.shopcode AND shop.shopcode=?;";
```

I have this query in a java method that takes the shopcode as an argument and returns an arraylist of all the events of that specific shopcode. The method is called in a jsp page in an if-else structure. The if which calls another method works just fine. The else with this sql query takes me to the error page. Could someone please tell me the right SQL query?

Comment: what did you mean failed ?

Comment: You'll have to better define what the problem is here. "Didn't work" is not very informative.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the "shopcode=?" portion?  That won't work in SQL.  If you're actually looking for where the shopcode is a question mark, you need to put it in single quotes.

Comment: Sorry I edited the initial post, hope it describes better my question now.

Comment: Have you tried displaying the MySQL error message?

Comment: @IoannaVikatou Sorry I haven't worked with java.  So it basically passes an array variable that replaces the question mark?  Do you just need to put "shopcode IN ?"?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?.. I'm confused.

```
SELECT * 
FROM event 
INNER JOIN shop 
  ON event.shopcode = shop.shopcode 
WHERE shop.shopcode = ?
```

Comment: I edited again my question. I hope it clarifies what I'm trying to say.

Comment: This is equivalent to his query. MySQL is permissive about putting `WHERE` conditions in `ON`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to move the shopcode filter after a where

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM event INNER JOIN shop ON event.shopcode=shop.shopcode WHERE shop.shopcode=?;";
```

Comment: While this is the preferred way to write it, MySQL is flexible and will treat the original code the same as this.